# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown triggers form submit (search)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="btn-toolbar search-dropdown" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-small">All Types</button>
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="search-type">
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="tv" value="TV">TV</input></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="Movies">Movies</input></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve..i think you need to adjust your code according to that

Comment: I don't want the search to be triggered when I click on the dropdown. :) that's all.

Comment: okay so are you saying that you don't want to close the dropdown when someone click on the check boxes...is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `<button>` elements submit their own form by default - they inherit the `type="submit"` attribute.

If you don't want 'em to do so, add the attribute `type="button"`, so it will become a normal button.

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me. I have a Bootstrap dropdown and a series of buttons after it in the same container. Selecting a dropdown item always triggers the next button. They are all set to type="button".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to close your drop down box when some click on the check box then you can do that like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<a>` element, rather than `<button>`, for the dropdown toggle.  The only downside is potential inconsistencies in rendering if you mix different types.  If you're worried about that, switch the submit button to an `<a>` also, and use javascript to submit the form onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-toolbar search-dropdown" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-small">All Types</button>
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="search-type">
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tv" value="TV" onclick="search()">TV</input></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="Movies" onclick="search()">Movies</input></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```